# How can I remove punctuation/period after lettered subexamples in g4be/xlist

Tags: lists, linguistics, examples, gb4e

I have to change sub examples in xlist environments (or rather g4be's `\ea \ea \ex \ex \ex \z \z` ) from being letter plus period, e.g. a. to simple parentheses (a) not followed by a period/full stop.

I have managed to get the parentheses using `\renewcommand\thexnumii{(\alph{xnumii})}` but I cannot remove the period so I have:

`\ea` 
`\ea`  blah blah blah 
`\ex` blah blah blah 
`\z` 
`\z`

which gives me 
(1)  (a). blah blah blah
  (b). blah blah blah

But I need the following:

(1)  (a) blah blah blah
  (b) blah blah blah

Do anyone have any idea how to do it? I've played with renewing xlista and xlisti but without luck; I'm probably missing something obvious or doing it wrong. Thanks.

Peace!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Although I was able to answer your question without one, it's really helpful in general to add a complete compilable example document to your question (similar to the one in my answer) rather than just showing code fragments so that people can see exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you!! yes in future I will. My preamble was simply so large that I didn't want to add too much complication, but I see it can be important.

Comment: Also, if an answer clearly solved your problem, it's helpful to others to "accept" it by clicking on the green checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes the `.` from only the level 2 subexamples, but not from more deeply embedded ones. I'm using the intended standard syntax, but the example works with the shorthands too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@xlist}{.}{\ifnum \@xnumdepth =2{}\else{.}\fi}{}{}
\renewcommand\thexnumii{(\@xsii{xnumii})}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex An example.
\begin{xlist}
\ex An embedded example.
\ex Another embedded example.
\end{xlist}
\ex Another example.
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]